# SharedPreferences Login

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create something that needs to get information in the first time and save it. The app starts at the MainActivity, if it does not have the information needed, the app send you to the MotoActivity. Once the app has the information you don't need to go to the MotoActivity anymore. I know i'm wrong but I don't know how to do.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

    editor.putInt("valid", 0);
    editor.commit();
    int n = sp.getInt("valid", -1);
    if(n == 0){
        editor.putInt("valid", 1);
        editor.commit();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MotoActivity.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check for the very first time that, if "userLoggedBefore" is true or false from the SharedPreferences, if the user had used the application before and had entered the right credentials, we will save authenticated to true and if he hasn't we will set the default value as false.

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Save", 0);
        boolean authenticated = sharedPref.getBoolean("userLoggedBefore", false);
```

then check -

```
if (authenticated){
//show your MainActivity
} else {
// show your MotoActivity
}
```

in your MotoActivity,

//if credentials matches

```
if(credentialMatches)
                            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                                    "Save", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref
                                    .edit();
                            prefEditor.putBoolean("userLoggedBefore", true);
                            prefEditor.commit();
else{ // if credentials doesn't match
                           SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Save", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref
                                    .edit();
                            prefEditor.putBoolean("userLoggedBefore", false);
                            prefEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: if it helped, you may set my answer as the right answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    // app already has the needed info.
    if(sp.getInt("valid", -1) == 1){
        // do something
    } 
    // app needs info. first, when you have got the info. in MotoActivity then set preferences key 'valid' to 1 
    else{
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MotoActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```